# DELETE Request doesnt work when using fetch (Axios works)

Tags: node.js, axios, fetch-api

i have following method to delete a webhook subscription:

```
const deleteSubscriptions = async (subscription: number) => {
    const url: string = `${CONFIG.STRAVA_API_BASE_URL}/push_subscriptions/${subscription}`;
    const params = {
        client_id: CONFIG.STRAVA_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CONFIG.STRAVA_CLIENT_SECRET
    };
    try {
        const res = await axios.delete(url, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            params: params
        });
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

This Method works fine but if i try to do the same with Fetch i receive an error.
Fetch Method:

```
const deleteSubscriptions = async (subscription: number) =>{
    const url: string = `${CONFIG.STRAVA_API_BASE_URL}/push_subscriptions/${subscription}`
    const body = JSON.stringify({
        client_id: CONFIG.STRAVA_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: CONFIG.STRAVA_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
    try{
        const res = await fetch(url, {
            method: "DELETE",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
            body: body

        })
        let data = await res.json();
    }catch (err: any){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive when using the fetch method:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URxUj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st request is sending your data as URL query parameters.  Your 2nd request is sending your data in the body of the request.

The 1st one is the right way to do it as the URL itself is supposed to represent the URL of the resource you want to delete and that is apparently what works with the host you are using.

I don't think DELETE is even supposed to have a body, just like GET isn't supposed to have a body.

And, neither request should be setting a Content-Type header since there's not supposed to be a body and the Content-Type applies to the body.

So, for `fetch()`, you need to put the parameters into the URL.  While `axios()` will do that for you, I don't see anywhere in the `fetch()` interface where it will do it for you so you may need to construct the URL with query parameters yourself before calling `fetch()`.

Comment: Thank you!
In postmen it worked via the body, but I think that it was then converted automatically